# WebPack cache file exceed file size limits when deploying NextJS app on CloudFlare Pages

Tags: webpack, next.js, cloudflare-pages

I am trying to deploy my NextJS app on CloudFlare Pages. However I get an error during building application process:
`Error: Asset ".next/cache/webpack/client-production/0.pack" is over the 25MiB limit. Size: 38331968 bytes`

Here is my deployment setting:

```
Build command: 
next build

Build output directory: 
/.next

Root directory: 
/

Environment variables: 
None
```

CloudFlare Pages has a limitation of 25MB per file and the file above exceed that limitation.
I don't know what this file is for. Is there a way to reduce its size (or just delete it) ?

Comment: Hey. We are facing a similar issue. How did you solve this?

Comment: hi @OmriHaim, I did not manage to solve it, I finally used Vercel to deploy my app